# Why I am getting these two errors? [wkhtmltoimage]

Tags: python, python-2.7, wkhtmltopdf, imgkit

Environment I am currently working:

- Windows 10
- Python27
- wkhtmltoimage 0.12.4
- imgkit module

This is my `example.py`

```
import os
import imgkit
imgkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'C:\out.jpg')
```

As this code clearly shows that I am trying to take the screenshot of the google website. But when I run this code in Windows 10 platform what I got, this errors.

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\testdns.py", line 3, in <module>
    imgkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'C:\out.jpg')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\imgkit\api.py", line 32, in from_url
    return rtn.to_img(output_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\imgkit\imgkit.py", line 240, in to_img
    raise IOError('wkhtmltoimage reported an error:\n' + stderr)
IOError: wkhtmltoimage reported an error:
Loading page (1/2)
Rendering (2/2)
Error: Could not write to output file
Error: Could not save image
Done
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

Now I don't know how to proceed

Comment: I don't think Windows 10 allows unprivileged programs to write to the root directory any more.  Choose an output path that's in your Documents folder, or some such location that you own.

Comment: Can you try this: `imgkit.from_url("http://google.com", "out.jpg")`

Comment: @jasonharper now this is awesome, How did you know that? Can you please tell me.

Comment: This is my new question. Would you like to see? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082123/this-code-of-python-is-working-very-slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
imgkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.jpg')
```

The above code will save image in root directory of the script. Or you can change `out.jpg` to any folder to which you have access like Documents Folder or Pictures Folder.

Comment: I did, the results are same, but I follow the @jasonharper answer and it worked perfectly.

Comment: But my answer and @jasonharper are almost the same

Comment: Okay, I did the same thing again, and the results are "The same error". Actually, the problem is windows 10 will not save the result in the root directory.